# Отправка http запроса в Django

Tags: django

Роюсь по интернету и никак не могу найти функцию на подобие requests.get для Django.
Дайте пожалуйста самый обычный способ по отправке GET/POST запросов, желательно с примером.

Comment: А что мешает просто использовать тот же самый requests.get?

Comment: Я изучаю django, попытался импортировать requests, но выходила ошибка.

Comment: Значит нужно прочитать текст ошибки, проанализировать причины её появления и исправить их

Comment: Вы допустили ошибку. Ни каких библиотек импортировать не нужно. Вот так вот правильно: request.get